# Проблемы с версткой для мобильного устройсва?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, мобильная-разработка

Верстаю страницу для мобильного устройства. Раньше всё (ширину, высоту, шрифты) необходимо было увеличивать и переносить блоки один под один.

А теперь станица как есть (как для экранов компьютеров) помещается в экран любого мобильного устройства.

И теперь размеры блоков и шрифты уже необходимо увеличивать?!
Может у меня какое-то свойство прописано, из-за которого так происходит?

Comment: Скорее всего, в браузере флажок "показать полную версию"

Comment: а где этот флажок в Google Chrome ? (

Comment: На устройстве - вверху справа три точки, в меню есть "Полная версия"

Comment: Хм, такого значка не вижу (Google Chrome последней версии обновлялся). Интересно что, когда добавляю линейку к устройству, то ширина как положено 320рх (для iphone5), но каким то чудетным образом в нее полностью помещаются блоки шириной 980рх. Может вопрос в CSS свойстве каком-то ?

Comment: Какую линейку. Я про устройство физическое. Телефон

Comment: Интересует через браузер на компьютере

Comment: Скорее всего, вы удалили нечто такое: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Возможно , спасибо! Если это прописываю, то на мгновение появляется на экране то,  чего я добиваюсь, а потом обратно все портится (может из-за скрипта или свойств css, хоть все подозрительное комментировалось) .Если будут еще идеи, напишите

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы найдено!)  нужно пропиcать в `<head>..</head>`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Странно,что раньше и без этого все работало. Надеюсь кому-то эта информация поможет)

ps: И проследить, что некоторые блоки не были строгой ширины, большем чем экран устройства ;)